# how can I get element in repeater?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am using protractor/jasmine for my js e2e tests. A problem I have now is how to select all items in a repeater? this is the angular repeater code:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in list"><a data-ng-click="selectItem(item)">{{item.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I run this script :

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in list')).then(function(items) {
     var ele= items[0].element(by.className('ng-scope'));
     ele.getText().then(function(text){
             console.log(text);
     });
});
```

the items object is  undefined? How can I get a reference to my repeater , select the 1st item and return the text?

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this

```
var list = element.all(by.repeater('item in list'));
expect(list.get(0).getText()).toBe('First item text');
```